# How to sort and delete columns in a multiindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiindexed dataframe (but with more columns)

```
                    2020-12-22 09:47:50          2020-12-23 16:43:45     2020-12-22 15:00 
Lines VehicleNumber                                          
102   9405                            3                      NaN             3
      9415                          NaN                       NaN           NaN
      9416                          NaN                      NaN            NaN
```

Now I want to sort the columns such that I have the earliest date as a first column and the lastest as last. After that I want to delete columns, which are not in between two dates let's say `2020-12-22  10:00:00 < date < 2020-12-23 10:00:00`. I tried transposing the dataframe, but it seems not to work when I have a multiindex.

Expected output:

```
                         2020-12-22 15:00         2020-12-23 16:43:45   
Lines VehicleNumber                                          
102   9405                            3                      NaN         
      9415                          NaN                      NaN        
      9416                          NaN                      NaN
```

So first we sort the columns by date and then check if they are between the two dates:
`2020-12-22  10:00:00 < date < 2020-12-23 10:00:00` hence delete one column

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe with expected output.

Comment: @MayankPorwal added

Comment: @wychen The output should not contain `2020-12-23 16:43:45 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert `str` columns to `date time` columns:

```
In [2244]: df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Then, sort `df` based on `datetimes`:

```
In [2246]: df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Suppose you want to keep only column that are greater than following:

```
In [2251]: x = '2020-12-22 10:00:00'
```

Use `List comprehension`:

```
In [2257]: m = [i for i in df.columns if i > pd.to_datetime(x)]

In [2258]: df[m]
Out[2258]: 
                     2020-12-22 15:00:00  2020-12-23 16:43:45
Lines VehicleNumber                                          
102   9405.0                         3.0                  NaN
9415  NaN                            NaN                  NaN
9416  NaN                            NaN                  NaN
```